# Electrical circuit question

Tags: electrical

All of the home wiring diagrams that I have seen online show outlets wired in a sequential chain. Is there a problem with having outlets on spurs originating in a junction box, as shown in the attached diagram? Looking at my house wiring in the basement, I notice that some of the living rooms sockets and all of the bedroom sockets are on spurs originating in a junction box. 
[image: Outlets on spurs]

Answer (score 4):

As long as the junction box is not over filled (as per code), the connection device (Wire-Nut®) is properly sized for all the wires, and the junction box remains accessible. There's no problem wiring the circuit in such a way.